# Generate ID numbers automatically if cells are not blank

Tags: excel, excel-formula

=COUNT(A$1:A2)+1
Column A (ID) generates numbers automatically. But in Column B (Products),I want to generate IDs where there is product data and not count blank cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use IF condition to generate ID or Line numbers
    =IF($B3="","",COUNT(A$1:A2)+1)